# SQL Syntax Error select * from

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code is throwing this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-contact-info' at line 1
```

my code:

```
<?php

    //connect
    $connection = mysqli_connect("myh","myu","myp","mydb") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //consultation: 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM web-contact-info"; 

    //execute the query. 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
        exit();
    }

    //display information: 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
      echo $row["live_name"] . "<br>"; 
    } 

    ?>
```

I've tried to put quotes around `web-contact-info` and get a slightly different error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''web-contact-info'' at line 1
```

What am I writing wrong?

Comment: Can't have dashes in your table name unless you use ticks

Comment: I've tried to put `'web-contact-info'` into single quotes like this. Is this what you mean by ticks?

Comment: why is my question being down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `web-contact-info`
```

As mysql_* is deprecated consider switching to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I've tried that. I get the second error shown above. I am using mysqli

Comment: In your example you are using ' not `.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the name of the table within simple quotes like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `web-contact-info`";
```

Comment: you shouldn't include `FROM` in within the ticks

Comment: sorry, the `` doesnt contains the FROM clause